# How to minimize the use of CTEs in a Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, optimization, common-table-expression, with-statement

The follow code works well with a small number of vector features. However when I run the query using a larger table (~35,000 rows), my memory use goes to 100% (32GB) and then I get a "Connection to the server has been lost" in pgadmin. I am running on localhost, so the issue is not network related. I'm guessing its because I am using to many CTE's (WITH queries). I was thinking of nesting the query in a PL/pgSQL loop and updating a table with the results. Thereby closing the temporary tables after each iteration. This seems like an inelegant solution and I was hoping someone might be able to show me how I can minimize the use of CTE's in the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE dem_stats AS
WITH
--  Select Features using lookup table and determine the raster tiles said features are intersecting
    feat AS 
        (SELECT title_no,
                a.grid_tile_name || '.asc' AS tile_name,
                a.wkb_geometry as geom
                FROM test_polygons a, parcels_all_shapefile_lookup_osgb_grid_5km b
                    WHERE a.title_no = b.olp_title_no
        ),
-- Merge rasters tiles from main raster file that intersect features        
    merged_rast AS
        (SELECT ST_Union(rast,1) AS rast
            FROM dem, feat
                WHERE filename
                    IN (tile_name)
        ),
-- As the tiles are now merged duplicates are not required
    feat_temp AS 
        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (title_no) * FROM feat
        ),
-- Clip merged raster and obtain pixel statistics
    b_stats AS
        (SELECT title_no, (stats).*
            FROM (SELECT title_no, ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(a.rast,1,b.geom,-9999,true)) AS stats
                FROM merged_rast a
                    INNER JOIN feat_temp b
                ON ST_Intersects(b.geom,a.rast)
            ) AS foo
        )
--  Summarise statistics for each title number
    SELECT title_no,
           count As pixel_val_count,
           min AS pixel_val_min,
           max AS pixel_val_max,
           mean AS pixel_val_mean,
           stddev AS pixel_val_stddev
            FROM b_stats
                WHERE count > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

though it is not exactly readable you can always inline the CTEs - this is sometimes a good idea because CTEs are optimization fences in PostgreSQL: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/